# Change the Transactional Replication Distributor on SQL 2000

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, replication

I have a server with about 3 replications configured.

- 3 databases being published to about 3 other servers
- there's a central Distributor

I need to know if I can change the distributor for one of the publishings and let the others or if I can only change all of the replication distributors at the publisher server.

And How to do this.

Example:

**ProdServer** has

- DB1 - Publishing
- DB2 - Publishing
- DB3 - Publishing

**DB1ReplSrv** has

- DB1 - Subscribing

**DB2ReplSrv** has

- DB2 - Subscribing

**DB3ReplSrv** has

- DB3 - Subscribing

**RplDistSrv** is the distributor for all of this.

Let's say I create a new server:
**NewRplDistSrv** I wan't slowly change the replications distributor server.

PS:I don't know if it's a Pull or Push Replication, how do I check this?

Sorry for my noobish question. But I would like to learn.

Thanks in advance,

Gabriel

Comment: when you say that you have a single central distributor are you referring to the distribution database or agent?

Comment: Agent. In Fact I would like to shut this whole distributor server off after the changes.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your question is, are you asking if it is possible to move your distribution database to a new server?

Comment: You can find out whether it's push/pull replication in the subscription properties (via r-click on subscription)

Comment: @Martin I'm using a dedicated distributor here, a whole server just for distributing my data. So its push publication, and the whole distributor is on another server, so the distributor database and agent are on another server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this.

I couldn't remove the distributor before because when I tried Enterprise Manager would hang forever.

I managed to do this by taking sql service offline on the **RplDistSrv** machine.

And only then trying to remove the configuration on **ProdServer**.

By the way I had to redo all current replications.

I had to reconfigure it in Enterprise Manager, by right clicking the **ProdServer** and selecting Replication I believe. this was done a while ago.

I found Enterprise Manager a bit confusing, sorry I couldn't give any step by step on how to do this.
But its doable if you stop the sql service of the distributor, and remove all replication config from the server. that uses the distributor. And then reconfigure it to use another server as replicator.